# Solving a linear system using matrices symbolically when variables are present in the input and output

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, linear-algebra

I want to use Sympy to symbolically solve a system of linear equations, but I have 0's in some spots which is causing linsolve to fail.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcGD4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkheW.png)

```py
import sympy as sp
a0,a1,b0,b1 = sp.symbols("a_0 a_1 b_0 b_1")
system = (sp.Matrix([[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]]),sp.Matrix([a0,a1,sp.S.Zero,sp.S.Zero]))
print(sp.linsolve(system,[b0,b1]))
#Returns the empty set
```

I understand why there's a problem, Sympy is trying to solve this system in terms of the input, b_0 and b_1, but since this matrix is technically inconsistent, there is no solution. However, if trying to solve from the output's perspective, there are valid solutions, namely a_0 = b_0,a_1 = a_0, and b_1 = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean be "from the output's perspective". These are your equations:

```
In [20]: A, b = system

In [21]: lhs = A*Matrix([x, y])

In [22]: equations = [Eq(lhs[i], b[i]) for i in range(4)]

In [23]: for eq in equations:
    ...:     pprint(eq)
    ...: 
x = a₀
x + y = a₁
y = 0
True
```

The last equation clearly shows that we need `y=0` but the first two equations imply that `y=a1-a0`. Since for almost all possible values of `a1` and `a0` we have that `a1-a0 != 0` it follows the for almost all values of the parameters the system does not have a solution.

If you want SymPy to find the values of e.g. `a0` and `a1` so that there is a solution then you can make those part of the unknowns in the problem:

```
In [25]: linsolve(equations[:3], [x,y,a0,a1])
Out[25]: {(a₁, 0, a₁, a₁)}
```

This says that you can have a solution for any value of `a1` provided `a0=a1`. and the solution will be `x=a1` and `y=0`.